Google Books Lookup & Auto FIll
I need to create a Google Books lookup from my current form & Autofill book details in the same form.
What i am developing is a Website where customers can sell their books listing on the site. For the ease of conveniece I am trying to add ISBN or Google Books api so customer once type the isbn no or Book name form should show the books available for that & Once customer clicks on it Details of this book should autofill in the same form.
I am using HivePress as the main listing plugin.

Welcome to WordPress Development. This site is dedicated to questions regarding core WP functionality. Your question seems to be about the Google Books api and/or HivePress, which are not subjects covered here.
